# Link shares for a library portal

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, share

We are developing a library portal for our university. On this library website, we usually share many links to many content providers.

We have a requirement to implement so that users can perform actions through out users' experience of the library website  including when using third-party content providers' platform.

For example: a user clicks on a content provider, from within the library website, continues browsing and when coming across an interesting article they should be able to share and/or save this article URL.

We have tried through utilizing an iframe whereby content providers covers the upper 90% of the page while the bottom 10% are used for call-for-action (save, share, etc).

This has failed due to obvious security reasons and all most all browsers does not support this if frame content resides outside our domain.

An alternative solution would be to implement a Chrome extension to achieve the same. However, forcing users to use a specific browser is not a healthy practice. Also we will face issues with mobile users.

I would appreciate listening to suggested workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an alternative of an iframe. I think when a user clicks on a link to a 3rd party content provider:

1. Your site captures that click event
2. Send the requested url to *your* server via AJAX
3. Your server access the requested site contents
4. Your server dumps the requsted url HMTL/Javascript contents onto a modal of size 90% pn the user's screen
5. The remaining 10% of the screen can be utilized for a toolbar or any controls you may want like sharing, saving the link etc.